# HTML video automatically download

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to automatically download a video file given a url that contains the link to the video. So far I have tried the approach of using `<a href='somelink' download>` but when I click on the link it will open a new tab containing the video instead of downloading it. Is there a way to write a script that automatically does the job that the video tag control options does? Like the picture shown below, can I write javascript to trigger the event on the download button? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might helpful.

```js
document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
```

```html
<a download="name_of_downloaded_file" href="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" id="myCheck"> Clicking on this link will force download the file</a>
```

Comment: Can you resolve CROS?

Comment: @LêDuyThứ are you talking about cross origin access?

Comment: Yes, your solution should be fine, but it won't solve the case where the server blocks cors. I've looked for other solutions but it seems that cors can't be resolved if I'm not the owner of the server.

Comment: @LêDuyThứ can you please add your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `target=”_blank”` along with anchor tag with download option to prevent streaming files directly in browsers on desktop and android or iOS (iPhone) devices.

```
<a href='somelink' download target=”_blank”>
```

Here is the [reference](https://tehnoblog.org/how-to-create-simple-html-video-files-download-page/)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me. The only change is that the video is opened in a new tab instead of the current one. My example is taken from here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download, and the video link I used is https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4, both of which are found on the w3school site.